# uisearchdisplaycontroller when search text is being typed in pushes navigationBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchresultscontroller

I am using iOS7 on iPad project.  In my controllers main view I have 2 subviews.  In one of the subviews I placed a tableview and above it a search bar and a button.  When I click on the search bar to enter text it grows by about 20 px pushing navigation bar up.  Can't figure out why it is doing so.  Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it just me then having this issue? Has anybody placed a search display control above a tableview and under a navigation bar successfully without this issue?

Comment: First of all ensure Use Autolayout unchecked under Utilities->File inspector